# Setting certain property on all products in one go

Tags: products-management, upgrade

I have imported some products into magento but I have problem with having them show up in front end.

How can I set all products at once to belong to main web shop, and how can I set all products that have quantity greater than 0 to be available in the stock?

Something like a bulk update if it exists or if there's some sql query I need to run. I'm new to magento so I'm not exactly sure what I'm supposed to do in such situation when I need to update all products at once.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to just use the Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Products -> Search for Qty above 0 -> select all -> actions dropdown:  update attributes -> select inventory tab -> click checkbox for "change" set to in stock. -> save.

Comment: @B00MER Thanks, that did the job well. Would you move your comment to an actual answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to via the Magento Admin:

1. Admin
2. Catalog
3. Manage Products
4. Search for Qty above 0
5. Select all
6. Actions dropdown: update attributes
7. select inventory tab
8. click checkbox for "change" set to in stock.
9. Save.